# Fixed radius on svg circle element when zoomed

Tags: javascript, svg

The situation for me is like I am drawing circles using svg.js and wish to keep the radius intact after zooming. That is, when zoomed the circle should not scale.
I am using panzoom.js which basically scales the viewbox and all the SVG elements to it. 
How can I stop the scaling of the SVG circle element while zooming ?

Help would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code so we can try to help you.

Comment: You have to use programming for this. Whenever zoom changes, set the new radius to the original radius divided by Zoom (zoom 1x : radius 20px, zoom 5x : radius 4px).